# Setting `fetch` headers for POST in `create-react-app`

Tags: reactjs, flask, cors, create-react-app

I'm completely stumped on this one.

I have pretty simple, small Flask app that wraps all responses with the headers

```py
    res.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    res.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
```

I have a React app, set up with `create-react-app` that makes requests. One `GET` request, accessed like this `const data = await fetch(new URL('photos', apiURL))` works just fine.

I'm trying to make a `POST` request to a different route now.

Client-side code:

```js
  const apiURL = 'http://localhost:8888';
  const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
  };
  const url = new URL(`photo-rename/${id}`, apiURL);
  const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify([{ new_name: currentName }]),
      headers,
  };
  fetch(url, options);
```

Server-side code:

```py
@APP.route('/rename/<name>', methods=['POST'])
def new_name(photo_name):
    data = request.get_json()
    # do stuff with data
    return add_headers(Response(json.dumps(['renamed: {}'.format(new_name)]), mimetype='application/json'))
```

I'm stuck in a loop where either I get a CORS error, or a 415 (unsupported media type) response.

When the code is as shown, I get a 200 on the pre-flight request, and a CORS error on the actual POST: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I then added `OPTIONS` to the flask route: `@APP.route('/rename/<name>', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])`. This leads me to the 415 error on the pre-flight request. Looking in the console, I see that the `Content-Type` header is `Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8` on the request, even though I set it to `application/json` in the fetch options.

I then tried adding `mode: 'no-cors'` to the request. This also leads to a 415 response (no pre-flight, just the POST request). In dev tools, I see again that the request headers include `Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8`.

For what it's worth, I can make the POST request successfully in Postman, which actually sets the headers `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`.

Is React overwriting headers somewhere? What else am I missing?

Comment: CORS headers are set on the server. You are not allowed to set them yourself. `no-cors` does not do what you want: https://evertpot.com/no-cors/

Comment: @Evert - any suggestions for what *would* work?

Comment: Take a look at the network tab of your browser for the request that failed. Which header are present? Compare that to do the error. You're probably doing something incorrectly on the flask side.

Answer (score 1):

In your `package.json` on the client, try adding a proxy to your API URL.

Should look something like:

`"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"`

Comment: I neglected to show that `apiURL` is in fact equal to `'http://localhost:8888'`, which I think makes this irrelevant. (I edited my question to clarify.) Or does it accomplish something else as well?